# Push call in Perl overwriting array

Tags: perl, arrays, push

Ok, here's the deal.  I have an array (inputted from a 400 MB file) where if I run the sort() command on it, comp runs out of memory.  The input file isn't the problem, so I've decided to break the initial array into smaller arrays that I can perform the sort on.  I can break the initial array into arrays of size 100k, which my code does.

(for the purposes of this testing, I've shrank the file from 400 MB to 40 MB)

I run my break array code, and on first iteration, i have an array of 100k as a reference in my @arrayList.  My code is just this:

```
push @arrayList, \@sorted;        #@sorted is the sorted version of the 100k array
$temp = @arrayList;               #returns 1, which it should 
@arrayTemp2 = @{$arrayList[0]};
$temp = @arrayTemp2;              #returns 100k, which it should
@arrayTemp2 = @{$arrayList[1]};
$temp = @arrayTemp2;              #returns 0 since it is uninitialized
```

On the next loop in the for loop, the sorted array is the rest of the initial array, only 23k.  Same code runs again, with these results:

```
push @arrayList, \@sorted;        #@sorted is the sorted version of the 23k array
$temp = @arrayList;               #returns 2, which it should 
@arrayTemp2 = @{$arrayList[0]};
$temp = @arrayTemp2;              #returns 23301, which is wrong
@arrayTemp2 = @{$arrayList[1]};
$temp = @arrayTemp2;              #returns 23301, which is right.
```

I've tried using every different way I can think of to fix this, and I just have no ideas left.  Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you are scoping it, you might be overwriting your memory when you update `@sorted`. See if this gives you better results:

```
push @arrayList, [ @sorted ];    # an array reference to a *copy* of @sorted
```

Comment: And it really is as simple as that... That makes me sad inside :P

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

If your loop uses the same `@sorted` variable (that is, it's declared/first used outside the loop scope), then Perl is working as expected here. `\@sorted` is a reference to the sorted array, and so it's always the same as the *current* value of `@sorted`, not the value at the time it was first referenced.